# Authentication and user creation on lambda serverless

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, serverless

I created a Lambda REST api (using serverless) that accesses a Dynamodb database and performs CRUD actions.

I then attached a CognitoUserPool and a CognitoUserClient with and ApiGatewayAuthorizer

Then problem I am now facing is that in order to identify I am using some terminal commands like this:

```
aws cognito-idp sign-up \
  --region myregion \
  --client-id clientid \
  --username username \
  --password mypassword
```

then I run:

```
aws cognito-idp admin-confirm-sign-up \
  --region myregion \
  --user-pool-id userpooolid \
  --username username
```

and finally to get the token I run

```
aws cognito-idp admin-initiate-auth --cli-input-json file://auth.json
```

where the json contains:

```json
{
   "UserPoolId":"myregion",
   "ClientId":"myclientid",
   "AuthFlow":"ADMIN_NO_SRP_AUTH",
   "AuthParameters":{
      "USERNAME":"username",
      "PASSWORD":"password"
   }
}
```

this gives me on the terminal a token that I then (manually) copy into Postman

where I test the API.

How can I make all this automatic and programmatically script all this?
Also I would like the users to signup and then authenticate.

I looked a some serverless example (in Python) but they are using Auth0, I would like to continue using AWS resources.

any ideas? or code that I could adapt to my needs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To achieve the same behavior programmatically,
You first need to decide which SDK you want to use.

For python users, you should use [boto3](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/index.html) which is the AWS SDK for python.

More specifically, to achieve the full sign-up process you can use the boto3 equivalents [sign_up](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/cognito-idp.html#CognitoIdentityProvider.Client.sign_up), [confirm_sign_up](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/cognito-idp.html#CognitoIdentityProvider.Client.confirm_sign_up), [admin_initaiate_auth](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/cognito-idp.html#CognitoIdentityProvider.Client.admin_initiate_auth).

As you can see the functions are very similar in names, also in request/response syntax.

Regarding a full code, this is not tested but it's based on AWS example code.

```
import boto3
from botocore.exceptions import ClientError


def sign_up(app_client_id, username, password):
    client = boto3.client('cognito-idp')

    try:
        sign_up_response = client.sign_up(
                ClientId=app_client_id,
                Username=username,
                Password=password
        )
        print(sign_up_response)

        confirm_sign_up_response = client.admin_confirm_sign_up(
                UserPoolId=deadpool['user_pool_id'],
                Username=deadpool['username']
        )
        print(confirm_sign_up_response)

     except ClientError as e:
         print(e)


def init_auth(app_client_id, username, password):
    client = boto3.client('cognito-idp')

    response = client.initiate_auth(
            AuthFlow='USER_PASSWORD_AUTH',
            AuthParameters={
                'USERNAME': username,
                'PASSWORD': password
            },
            ClientId=app_client_id
    )

    print(response['AuthenticationResult']['AccessToken'])
    print(response['AuthenticationResult']['IdToken'])
    print(response['AuthenticationResult']['RefreshToken'])
```

As you can see there are 3 types of tokens, to have a better understanding refer [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/amazon-cognito-user-pools-using-tokens-with-identity-providers.html#amazon-cognito-identity-user-pools-using-id-and-access-tokens-in-web-api).